# Seeking correct syntax for curl POST command that puts out a JSON record

Tags: json, post, curl, wget

This is the syntax I am using for my curl POST command:

**curl -d 'username:"admin",password:"secret"' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://xxx.xxx.me:9080/v2.0/tokens**

I run it, and it echoes on the client-side:

{"username:\"admin\",password:\"secret\"":""}

I was expecting:

{"username:\"aadmin\",password:\"secret\"}

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"secret"}' http://xxx.xxx.me:9080/v2.0/tokens
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no good: {"{\"username\":\"admin\", \"password\":\"secret\"}":""}

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"secret"}' http://xxx.xxx.me:9080/v2.0/tokens
```

Comment: No better luck: {"{\"username\":\"admin\", \"password\":\"secret\"}":""}

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out by trial and error.

syntax for curl POST that puts out a JSON record:

**curl -d 'username=admin&password=secret'  http://xxx.xxx.me:9080/v2.0/tokens**

syntax for wget POST that puts out a JSON record:

**wget --post-data='username=admin&password=secret' http://xxx.xxx.me:9080/v2.0/token**

On Mac (OSX 10.7),  curl --version is 7.21.4 and on Linux Centos 6.2, curl --version is 7.19.7

On Mac (OSX 10.7), wget --version is 1.13.4 and on Linux Centos 6.2, wget --version is 1.12

Back end server is node.js version is v0.10.21 but I don't think the back end matters - The back end could be a PHP Apache server is anything else.

I know that I stand in contradiction with the official answers on this day, 12 Aug 2014 but I don't know what to make of that contradiction.